# Need a simple ASP.NET asynchronous callback to web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, asynchronous

I have been trying to figure this our for far too long and I cannot get my head around it. Every example I have seen seems to be far more complex that I need.

I have a web service in my project (.asmx). I want to call it very simply from a button on a webpage.

1. Click
2. Run service asynchronously
3. return control back to webpage (web
   service running in background)

Can someone show me a simple example in vb, or even something they think will help me better understand what I need to do?

Comment: The thing you are requesting runs on the client, not the server, so it uses javascript, not VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the jQuery library (not the only option, but a darn good one) vastly simplifies this problem. Here's an example of what to put in your button's onclick event:

```
$.post('MyWebService.asmx', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <Contact xmlns="http://mywebsite.com/">
        <firstName>string</firstName>
        <lastName>string</lastName>
      </Contact>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>');
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks John. Should I look in to using jQuery instead of asp.net Ajax? They don't need each other to work, correct?

Comment: ASMX services support JSON, which is a *much* simpler way of passing data into and out of services.  For a few examples: http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: @IMAbev (1) My experience has been that the jQuery post method was easy to implement, and ASP.NET Ajax wasn't. (2) No, the 2 approaches do not need each other.

Comment: Good John, thank. I looked over the jQuery documentation this weekend and worked with some of the examples. It doesn't look too daunting.